# Simple C*-algebra under minimal norm

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A, B$ be two simple C*-algebras, it is known that $A\otimes_{min}B$ is simple. Here, "simple" means there are no non-trivial closed two sided ideal, and the norm is using minimal norm(or spatial norm).

I want to verify this result, in *Operator Algebras* of Blackadar, this result is true because of the minimality of the spatial norm(P.187). But I can't figure out the proof. I believe the main idea of the proof is obtaining contradiction, then I get stuck. Can anyone give me some hints to proceed?

Comment: Are you wondering about the proof of minimality of the spatial norm or the fact that $A\otimes_\min B$ is simple, whenever $A$ and $B$ are, assuming minimality of the spatial norm?

Comment: The latter one, assuming minimality of the spatial norm.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\pi_A\otimes\pi_B$ be the representation of $A\odot B$ which induces the min norm i.e. $\|\pi_A\otimes \pi_B(x)\|=\|x\|_{min}$ (by Corollary II.6.4.9. in Blackadar) since $A$ and $B$ are simple this representation is *faithful*.

Suppose $A\otimes_{min} B$ is not simple, so there is a proper closed two-sided $*$-ideal $J\in A\otimes_{min} B$. Hence, there is a $*$-homomorphism $\phi:A\otimes_{min} B \rightarrow A\otimes_{min} B/J$ and $$\|\phi(\pi_A\otimes \pi_B(x))\|\leq \|\pi_A\otimes \pi_B(x)\|=\|x\|_{min}$$ (by Corollary II.1.6.6. in Blackadar), which
contradicts the minimality of the min-norm.

Comment: What is the contradiction here?

Comment: $\|\cdot\|_{min}$ is the smallest $C^*$-norm on $A\odot B$.

Comment: Still no contradiction. You have $\le$ and not $<$...

Comment: @QuantumSpace right... what if I pick $x\neq 0 \in J$, then don't I get that $\|\phi((\pi_A\otimes \pi_B)(x))\|=0$ while $\|x\|_{min}>0$?